# IncludeJsFile doesn't load from within the templates directory

Tags: templating

Anyone know what could be wrong? It doesn't load files residing in /craft/templates/js that I include with for example `{% includeJsFile "/js/file.min.js" %}`, only if the js folder is in the public folder.

Comment: That should work out of the box – very odd. You might want to turn on [`devMode`](https://craftcms.com/support/dev-mode) and visit the URL to your JS assets directly (e.g. "http://example.com/js/file.min.js") in your browser, just to see what Craft spits out. Also, check your logs in `/craft/storage/runtime/logs` for `[error]` messages. In any case; be advised that keeping JS and/or CSS files in the `/templates` folder is [not best practice](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/15453/1098) – unless you have a very good reason, you should always serve JS & CSS from your public folder.

Comment: Will check it out and report back.